# Adding text to bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I wonder if there is a *simple* way to add a line of text to bibliography?

Let's say I make an inline bibliography using thebibliography environment and wish to add a line between two bib-items, e.g.,

```
BIBLIOGRAPHY
[1] AAA
[2] BBB
Here text comes in.
[3] CCC
etc.
```

I've seen a number of similar topics, but they seem to deal with some specific problems, e.g., when the numbering changes etc. Isn't there a way just to add a line of text?

**EDIT:** I tried the approach proposed by @David (as I understood it), but it produces two separate Bibliography sections:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}
XXX

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{A1}
  Ref A1
\end{thebibliography}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\setcounter{enumiv}{1}
\bibitem{B1}
  B1
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Regarding what I want to achieve: I wish to split the embedded bibliography into 2, at most 3 parts by some separating lines of text.

Comment: close the environment, add the text, restart the environment, set the counter to 3 ?

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: @Mico, it's report.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, good point, thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the OP uses a `bibliography` environment (with or without a `bibtex` file) the proposed solution to close and reset the label and reopen the bibliography environment might not work.

Comment: Can you provide an MWE showing what you want to achieve?  Is the text after a note/annotation relative to the preceding bibitem?

Comment: @Guido if the OP provided an example someone would show  how to make it work in that case. Depending on exactly what definition is used, you may need to extract the inner list part and avoid duplicated headings, but given a definition to copy from it is only a matter of copying the right bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The definition of the environment in `report` is

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
....
```

So for the restarted version you want to keep the list but lose the chapter heading, something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}
XXX

\let\savedchapter\chapter % just if you need real chapters later
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{A1}
  Ref A1
\end{thebibliography}
\renewcommand\chapter[2]{}% eat * and the title in \chapter*{\bibname}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\setcounter{enumiv}{1}
\bibitem{B1}
  B1
\end{thebibliography}

\let\chapter\savedchapter
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thanks!