# I want to add a section in in the same page where my bibliography ends

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

As the title says, I want to add a section that says: "some texts that the author found useful" right after the bibliography and list down the texts that I didn't cite within the paper. Something like this [Adding text to bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524738/adding-text-to-bibliography) but I have created my bibliography with Bibtex.

**EDIT** Here is the skeleton frame of what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}
XXX
\bibiliography(bib)
\end{document}
```

And my bibliography comes out as:

```
BIBLIOGRAPHY
[1] AAA
[2] BBB
[3] CCC
```

But I want it to show it as:

```
BIBLIOGRAPHY
[1] AAA
[2] BBB

The following are some text that the author found useful:
[1] CCC
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Please provide a MWE example showing what you have so far.

Comment: edited content @oliversm

Comment: I think I got it. I just followed the instructions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524738/adding-text-to-bibliography by editing the bbl file.